# Using C#-Language Server of Visual Studio 2019 in VSIX Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, language-server-protocol

I'd like to create a new extension that allows some kind of text templating similar to Microsoft's T4 runtime text templating engine.

Those templates can contain C# code and I'd like to have LSP functionality for these snippets within the Visual Studio text editor, i.e. renaming, go to definition, hover tips etc.

Is there a way to use/connect to the existing C# language server in such a way that I can send the C# code snippets to it for processing?

How does the Razor engine in ASP.net do it?

Comment: The Razor support code base is at GitHub, https://github.com/dotnet/razor-tooling so if you have time you can dig all goodies out.

Comment: Thanks, I know about the repository already. Without any leads on where to start looking in the code-base I think it is unfathomable for me due to inexperience on my side. I‘m hoping someone with experience can help me get started.

Comment: Sadly Microsoft didn't have complete documentation around that repo, but the top project is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServerClient.Razor.csproj` and the things handling Razor/HTML/C# is in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServer.ContainedLanguage.csproj`. The project descriptions give you minimal hints on what they are and whether you should look deeper.

Comment: Digging for a while revealed to me, that the Razor project uses the OmiSharp C# language server internally (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/razor-tooling/blob/main/src/Razor/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.LanguageServer/RazorLanguageServer.cs#L79)). As it seems for the C# LSP to be working within Razor documents all of the source files/packages/projects referenced in the opened project need to be parsed by OmniSharp. That means that there are two separate C# LSPs running with the same data. The one VS comes with and OmniSharp. Shame...